# Writing modified buffer to a temporary file

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I'd like to write the modified buffer I'm currently editing to a temporary file periodically. In the background I could then, for example, use external tools to analyze the file.

I don't want to write the file to it real location in this process - I want the user to be in charge of that through the normal `:w` command.

How can I do this in a vimscript called by the `CursorHold` autocommand? Vim 7.4 and up is fine.

Comment: You can run external tools directly on the content (or parts) of your buffer with `:[range]w !command`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is rather simple:

```
:autocmd CursorHold *
\   let save_modified = &modified |
\       silent! execute 'write' fnameescape(tempname()) |
\   let &modified = save_modified
```

However, this has the side effect of naming a `:new` buffer on the first triggering. (It doesn't affect existing files; this is the difference between `:write` and `:saveas`.) You can either add another check (`empty(bufname(''))`) and undo that via `:0file`, or move to lower-level functions altogether:

```
:autocmd CursorHold * call writefile(getline(1, '$'), tempname())
```

The caveat of this approach is that the file contents will always be persisted

- with Vim's `'encoding'` setting, i.e. you lose any custom `'fileencoding'` of the original buffer, and
- with Unix (LF) line endings (which you could restore with a `map()` over the list returned by `getline()`).