# How to properly organize persistence of the vim state of all opened buffers?

Tags: buffers, sessions, hidden-buffers

Before switching to vim years ago I was using Sublime Text and it perfectly handled situations when I just close it and open again. Nothing is lost and at the place where I left it off. So I'm aiming to reproduce that behaviour in Vim. What I have already is [xolox/vim-session](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session) set up and running and swap files properly working as I expect them to. However, I encountered an issue that I create a new buffer without a name and it's not possible to restore it when I close vim and open it again. I would use a temporary file name as it mentioned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/writing-modified-buffer-to-a-temporary-file) but I'm no so sure that this is the best approach to take.

So, my question is how to properly organize session save and restore even for unsaved buffers without a name?

Comment: If you use terminal Vim, I’d advocate using `<C-z>` or `:suspend` as a “close”—sessions (afaik) cannot keep unsaved unnamed buffers around. If you want to keep it, the text needs to stay in memory (background/foreground) or be saved. [this is a comment because i might be wrong]

Comment: Hidden or unloaded buffers? Yes. Unsaved buffers? No, vim doesn't have a way to persist those in the session. Using a temporary file sounds as good as any other idea. (Unless backgrounding the process as D. Ben Knoble describes works for you.)